# The meaning of the results from decomposeHomographyMat

Tags: opencv, homography, homogenous-transformation

I have a single calibrated RGB camera that is moving around a static object. I took two consequence shots and compute the Homography between them.

Then, using Camera Matrix and Homography, I call `cv::decomposeHomographyMat` which gives me possible rotations angles and translations.

Suppose that always the first pair of rotation and translation the correct one, what do those angles and translation mean? What is the origin of this transformation? Is it about the camera origin? Is it about the object origin?

Answer (score 0):

`decomposeHomographyMat`, and indeed any method that computes 3D camera motion just from images, can only compute *relative* motion between the cameras. It is impossible to compute poses in some fixed external world coordinate frame. For  `decomposeHomographyMat` the output is defined as the relative camera motion (3D rotation and translation) from the first camera position to the second camera position.  As an additional point, you can't assume the first camera pose from `decomposeHomographyMat` is always the correct one, and the translation solution is correct up to an unknown scaling factor.